# Unlock folder using c sharp

Tags: c#

I am doing folder lock project using C#, and I am able lock the folders successfully but while unlocking, it's not working properly. My code is:

```
FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider improving your question.

Comment: Probably you removed yourself privileges to modify permissions.

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your code to following manner

```
FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(
  adminUserName, 
  FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
  AccessControlType.Deny);

ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);
```